# How to create a custom schema type with typescript for mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm setting up a schematic type to understand how it works with typescript and mongoose. The example validates an email with a simple regex, but I do not know how to inject into the declarations of mongoose.d.ts

How can this work?

## email.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'

function Email (path: any, options: any[]) {
  mongoose.SchemaType.call(this, path, options, 'Email')
}

Email.prototype = Object.create(mongoose.SchemaType.prototype)

Email.prototype.cast = function (email: string) {
  if (!/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid email address')
  }
  return email
}

// Typescript: Property 'Email' does not exist on type 'typeof Types'.
mongoose.Schema.Types.Email = Email
```

## email.d.ts

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
  namespace Schema {
    namespace Types {
      // ???
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get to this result in the scheme

```
const schema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: Email
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you really need to add new type into `mongoose.Schema.Types`, if you're using it "as-is"? TS didn't throw any error if I just took your definition for `Email` and your scheme (aside from "implicit `this`").

Comment: the ts did not play error, I needed to mount a different type pos will be used in several different models :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally did, I did a function but I think I can improve! :)

### index.d.ts

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
  namespace Schema {
    namespace Types {
      function Email (path: string, options: any): void
    }
  }
}
```

### email.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'

function Email (path: string, options: any): void {
  mongoose.SchemaTypes.String.call(this, path, options)

  function isValid (val) {
    // validation logic
  }

  this.validate(isValid, options.message || 'invalid email address')
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Email.prototype, mongoose.SchemaTypes.String.prototype)

mongoose.Types.Email = Email
mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email = Email
```

Answer (score 0):

**email.ts**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default class Email extends mongoose.SchemaType {
    cast(email: string) {
        if (!/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid email address')
        }
        return email
    }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.Email = Email;
```

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
    namespace Schema {
        namespace Types {
            class Email extends SchemaType {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine but where did you find that regex? There are [many of them](https://emailregex.com/) that work differently and which don't match the same emails

Comment: @NinoFiliu, I get your point, but I just repeated the validation used in the question. My point was to show a simple and styled way to add a new schema type to mongoose.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that the OP used the same regex! Alright then.